# Test JSP login with curl

Tags: jsp, curl, testing, authentication

I'm trying to validate the credentials (user/password) of a webpage using curl, but I tried in many ways.

I had some support from the developer tools of Chrome to generate the string needed using the network or console tool.

The URL: `http://localhost:8080/site/login.do`

Chrome tools suggested:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/egsdp/j_security_check' \
    -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
    -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' \
    -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' \
    -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36' \
    -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' \
    -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/egsdp/login.do' \
    -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
    -H 'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,it;q=0.5,pt;q=0.4,sr;q=0.3,tr;q=0.2,zh-CN;q=0.1,zh;q=0.1,gl;q=0.1' \
    -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=100E2B441254401942BF64876B18F584' \
    --data 'j_username=root&j_password=AWYc2d9%2B1mc%3D' \
    --compressed
```

I look into the source code of the login web page:

```
<div id="formulario">
  <form method="post" id="formLogin" action="">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
        <th align="right">Usuario:</th>
        <td align="left">
          <input type="text" name="j_username" size="15"> 
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th align="right">Contrase?a :</th>
        <td align="left">
          <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" size="15">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><input type="button" value="Login"
        onclick="javascript:peticion()">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

What's wrong with my curl?

Comment: IMHO you need to add `-X POST` to the curl parameters. The form is expected to be sent by POST, but curl by default sends GET.

Comment: you can also add `-v` for verbose mode in curl
besides, if you referring to  `j_security_check` servlet itself, you most probably getting exception like referring to login page itself. `j_security_check` is protecting the resources you are trying to access, not the login page.